# Rails 3 coffeescript controller association?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

Alright, I'm a JS / JQuery / Coffeescript noob. This is probably easy points for someone.

Having successfully implemented RBate's Nested Form Model railscast, I am attempting to reproduce this in a simpler model: Chapters have many counties.

I have a `chapters.js.coffee` file with the following code:

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('#destroy').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()
```

This code works just fine in the other model. But not here.

`_chapters_form.html.erb:`

```
<div class="row span12">    
<%= form_for(@chapter) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="span2"><strong>Chapter name:</strong></div>
    <div class="span6"><%= f.text_field :name %></div>
    <div class="span2"><strong>Chapter Number:</strong></div>
    <%= f.number_field :chapter_num, class: "span2" %>
</div>
<div class="row span12">
<div class="span12">
    <%= f.fields_for :counties do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'county_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
</div>
    <% if f.object.new_record? then link = 'Add the Chapter' else link = 'Update Chapter' end %>
      <%= f.submit "#{link}", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Cancel", chapters_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

and:

`_county_fields.html.erb:`

```
<fieldset>
<div class="well span12">
    <div class="row span12">
        <div class="span3">County Number: <br /><i>(6-digit FIPS code)</i></div>
        <div class="span2"><%= f.number_field :county_num %></div>
        <div class="span2">County Name:</div>
        <div class="span5"><%= f.text_field :name %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row span12"><hr></div>
    <div class="row span12">
        <div class="span6">Move to new Chapter:</div>
        <div class="span6"><%= select(:county, :chapter_id, Chapter.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}) %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row span12">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy, id: "destroy" %>
            <%= link_to "remove county", "#", class: "remove_fields" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

There are no errors in the JS. Again, noob speaking, but it doesn't seem that the JS is getting called. Clicking `<%= link_to "remove county", "#", class: "remove_fields" %>` just adds the `#` to the  URI.

What am I doing wrong?

As requested, the [HTML in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiperific/A24D4/1/) which doesn't work either.

Comment: FYI, the Coffeescript notes say the files should be named to associate with the controller. The `chapters_controller.rb` exists. The views are all working fine, the form submits fine. No problems.

Comment: Are these partials all under the same controller, or different ones? (working and non working forms)

Comment: The partials are all in the `app/views/chapters` folder. They are not being rendered through the controller (like an AJAX call). They are rendered in the HTML as shown. The partials are all viewing and submitting properly. Just no JS gets executed when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is broken. You open a div before the form element, then close it before you close the form. If you move the form element up to just inside the container div, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/B638u/).

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/chapters/7" class="edit_chapter" id="edit_chapter_7" method="post">
      <div class="row-fluid">
...
     </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

You should take more care in the indenting of your HTML to help avoid this sort of simple mistake. Code format matters.

Comment: I would have bet $5,000 that my divs were all correct. In fact, I said terrible things about you when I first read your response. Then I went back and, sure enough, I had left a hanging </div> tag. I take back everything and restore to you the title of 'master of the internet.'

Answer (score 1):

The page on which they appear - regardless of how they are rendered - must be an action of the `chapters_controller` for `chapters.js.coffee` to be included. My bet is that the script is not being included at all, as the code looks fine. Check out the pages you are having issues with with this code:

```
jQuery ->
  console.log "included chapters.js.coffee"
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    console.log "clicked .remove_fields"
    $(this).prev('#destroy').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()
```

Also, post up the rendered HTML in your question

Comment: Ok, again, noob here. When you say "the pages on which they appear", does 'they' mean the partials? Do you mean to render the partials from the controller and not the view? When I source the HTML, the head includes this: `<script src="/assets/chapters.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>` from the asset pipeline, so I feel like the function should be accessible.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap, so there are lots of divs which make the HTML ugly. I added a link to a fiddle where I also pasted the rendered JS as pulled from Chrome inspector.

Comment: @Vox helped me find the solution. I'm sure you were on the right track, in fact, I learned quite a bit from your console.log approach, so I'm up voting. Thanks!